# Continuity and derivative

Tags: calculus

Is the the following statement true?

If $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=3$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=3$.

My answer is false for uncertain reason, that is, the sided limits of does not guarantee equality of the two equations. May I know what is your opinion on this?

Answer (score 2):

If you set $h=x-1$, you get,
$$3=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h},$$

and thus it's true.

Comment: but what about the condition for the sided limits?

Comment: We assume the first limit is well defined. Since h is a continuous and differentiable function, we should be in good shape

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true. You can make a *change of variables*. Say you have
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x- 1}
$$
you can then let $h = x-1$ (and so $x = h+1)$. Observe that as $x$ approaches $1$, then $h$ approaches $0$, so the limit is the same as
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h + 1) - f(1)}{ h}.
$$
The limit(s) are exactly the definition of $f'(1)$ (when the limit exists).

Comment: ok thanks...now I get it